# 'subl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file on Windows

Tags: command-line, cmd, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using Windows as my Operating System.

My drive(f:) folders look like this:

```
f:/
----> myproject/
--------> db.sqlite3
--------> manage.py
--------> db.sqlite3
```

I want to open my `myproject` folder with SublimeText3 in `cmd` in Windows.

In `cmd` I navigate to my project directory (F:\my project) and enter this command:

```
subl .
```

I get this result:

```
'subl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comman)

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `subl` as an [Environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) so that cmd can find the program.

Go to **Control Panel\System and Security\System** and click "**Advanced system settings**". Go to the "**Advanced**" tab and click on "**Environment Variables...**". Add the directory containing *subl.exe* to the end of the *Path* variable in "System variables", e.g.

> ;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3

The semicolon separates the values in the Path variable, so don't forget to add it.

Restart your command line, and you should be able to use subl.

Comment: I was troubleshooting this for a little bit and this is the only post I saw mention the semicolon. Lo and behold it was fixed. This should be higher

Answer (score 2):

So your System does not know where to find `subl`

You need to tell it where it is. So find where the executable is.

Then Right click `Computer` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced System Settings` -> `Environment Variables`
then add the Path of where the file exits into PATH by using semicolon to separate it from the previous path.

for instance `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\`

Alternatively, run the full path each time to `subl` in your scripts.